# Rails: Pulling results for a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations, polymorphism

I have a the following polymorphic association set up:

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favoritable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, :as => :favoritable
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What I ultimately want to do is pull all the photos a specific user has favorited.

How would I make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for this:

`Photo.joins(:favorites).where("favorites.user_id = ?", user_id)`

This will return an Array of Photo objects (along with joined fields from Favorite) that a specific user has favorited. You'll have to pass in the user_id to this call.